# Play the silverlight player from outside the silverlight object

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a simple Silverlight player that uses the MediaElement. For reasons out of my control, they want to be able to have all the play/pause/stop, volume controls etc. based in the ASP.NET code and not be built in Silverlight. I embed the Silverlight in my aspx as follows:

```
<object id="SilverlightPlayer" data="data:application/x-silverlight," 
                                    type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="750" height="460" >
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/VideoPlayer.xap"/>  
<param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
<param name="OnResize" value="HandleResize" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<param name="initParams" id="SLInitParameters" value='video=MyVideo.wmv' />                    
</object>
```

I want to have the user click a "Play" button in the ASPX and it will tell the Silverlight player to play the video. (Same kind of thing for all the other buttons) I have been unable to find out how to do this anywhere since everyone it seems builds these controls into their Silverlight.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
I am using the following to recreate the silverlight:

```
function CreateSilverlight(hostElement, source, initParams) {
        var pluginId = hostElement.id + "PluginId";

        hostElement.innerHTML = Silverlight.createObject(source, null, pluginId,
            {
                width: '750',
                height: '460',
                background: 'black',
                isWindowless: true,
                alt: '<!--Silverlight not installed-->',
                data: 'data:application/x-silverlight,',
                type: 'application/x-silverlight-2',
                EnableGPUAcceleration: true,
                version: '4.0',
                autoUpgrade: true
            },
            { onError: null, onLoad: null, OnResize: HandleResize },
            initParams, hostElement.id);
}
```

So I don't have the reference to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of your silverlight page on which the media element appears, call:

```
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("player", this)
```

Then, you can add methods to your page like this:

```
[ScriptableMember]
public void Play()
{
    this.MediaElement.Play();
}

[ScriptableMember]
public void Pause()
{
    this.MediaElement.Pause();
}

[ScriptableMember]
public void Stop()
{
    this.MediaElement.Stop();
}
```

Those `[ScriptableMember]` attributes are important.  Then, from javascript, you can do:

```
var slApp = document.getElementById("SilverlightPlayer");
slApp.player.Play();
```

That would call the exposed "Play" method, which in turn tells the `MediaElement` to `Play()`.

Comment: One problem with this....I am loading different initParams because the user can click a link to watch a different video. So I use the  Silverlight.createObject() from javascript to reload the player with new initparams. When I do this, document.getElementById("SilverlightPlayer"); returns a null value. Any ideas?

Comment: createObject returns a reference to the object itself, so you wouldn't need to get it from document.getElementById.  Alternatively, pass "SilverlightPlayer" as the "id" parameter in createObject()

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate from HTML to Silverlight via Javascript through the  HtmlPage.Window.Invoke() method. [Check out this link](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx).

Comment: That example shows how to invoke Javascript from Silverlight. I want my Javascript to invoke a method in my Silverlight.

Comment: The steps under the heading "Calling Silverlight From Java script:" doesn't count? :-) Look for the "TalkToJavaScript" method example.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to reload the silverlight control to get it to load a different video. I just needed to pass a new media path to the silverlight mediaElement.Source via the JS to silverlight bridge. I also solved my issue of loading a video passed to the page by adding   to invoke a js function once the SL was loaded on the screen.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  Make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that other may learn from your success.  Cheers~